# how to achieve 100% width with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I just got into working with bootstrap and can't set my width to 100%. I tried assigning `width:100%;` on my container CSS but that didn't work. the only solution I came across was setting `container-fluid no-padding` in my div class(and it works) but I read that setting no-padding is bad because it goes against bootstraps 15px padding preset. What is the correct way of setting the width to 100% in bootstrap? Thanks in advance.

Html

```css
.con-1{
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;

}

.row-1{
    border: 3px solid red;
    background-color: white;
    height: 75%;
}

.row-2{
    border: 3px solid red;
    background-color: white;
    height: 25%;
}

.col-1{
    border: 3px dotted blue;
    width: 95%;
}

.col-2{
    border: 3px dotted blue;
    width: 5%;
}

.col-3{
    border: 3px dotted blue;
    width: 31.6%;
}

.col-4{
    border: 3px dotted blue;
    width: 31.6%;
}

.col-5{
    border: 3px dotted blue;
    width: 31.6%;
}

.col-6{
    border: 3px dotted blue;
    width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container con-1">
  <div class ="row row-1">
      <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-1">
          Row 1 Col 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-2">
          Row 1 Col 2
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class ="row row-2">
      <div class="col col-3">
          Row 2 Col 1
      </div>
      <div class="col col-4">
          Row 2 Col 2
      </div>
      <div class="col col-5">
          Row 2 Col 3
      </div>
      <div class="col col-6">
          Row 2 Col 4
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `container-fluid` instead of `container` - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

Answer (score 1):

**There are several methods to achieve this.**

If you want to have a true 100% width element, simply put a `w-100` class on your div without `container`.

In your case, when you are using a `container`, switch it to a fluid one by replacing it with `container-fluid`, and adding a `p-0` class as well.

Please refer to the Bootstrap documentation:
[Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/), [Containers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/#containers)

Comment: won't the p-0 class interfere with the bootstrap 15px padding grid system?@dhgy

Comment: It will, but it is not against Bootstrap's rules. If you want to skip the `p-0` class, the width will be `100% - 15px - 15px`.

Answer (score 0):

As @pete suggested Using `container-fluid` instead of container will solve this issue and set the container width to 100%.

```html
<div class="container-fluid con-1">
  <div class ="row row-1">
      <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-1">
          Row 1 Col 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-2">
          Row 1 Col 2
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class ="row row-2">
      <div class="col col-3">
          Row 2 Col 1
      </div>
      <div class="col col-4">
          Row 2 Col 2
      </div>
      <div class="col col-5">
          Row 2 Col 3
      </div>
      <div class="col col-6">
          Row 2 Col 4
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```